# Recursive countLeave function

Tags: java

I'm trying to count the leaves of a binary tree but the recursive function always returns 0.

Can someone help me out?

```
public static int countLeaves(BinaryTree tree) {
    if (tree.emptyTree()) {
        System.out.println("im here ");
        return 0;
    }

    if (tree.getLeft() == null && tree.getRight() == null) {
         System.out.println("but I'M NEVER HERE "); // doesn't get in
         return 1;
    } else {
        return countLeaves(tree.getLeft()) + countLeaves(tree.getRight());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `tree.emptyTree()` code look like?

Comment: what is the class `BinaryTree`?

Comment: What is the difference between your emptyTree() code and your if (tree.getLeft()==null && tree.getRight()==null) ?

Comment: Take a binary tree with one node. Debug with IDE you are familiar with (if there is none, try Eclipse). Take a binary tree with two nodes, do the same, and so on until you get the right result. This is the only way to learn.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ -- but @JohnDonn is right, stepping through with a debugger is the way to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the explanation comments in the code.

```
public static int countLeaves(/* @Nullable */ BinaryTree tree) {
    if (tree == null) {
        // Guardian clause
        return 0;
    } else if (tree.getLeft()==null && tree.getRight()==null) {
        // This is a leaf node ==> count this leaf.
        return 1;
    } else {
        // This is a non-leaf node ==> recursive call. 
        return countLeaves(tree.getLeft()) + countLeaves(tree.getRight());
    }
```

}

In your code, you had duplicated `if` condition for the same case (I'm now assuming that `tree.emptyTree()` returned `true` if and only if both children are `null`). Hence, the second `if` is unreachable -> `but I'M NEVER HERE`.

Another problem is that you are not handling the case when *either* `left` *or* `right` is `null` (and the other node is non-`null`). This is only ok if you are dealing with *full* binary trees.

Comment: Your code basically looks right.  I think the check for `tree.emptyTree()` was the problem.

Comment: Downvoted because even with (brief) explanatory comments, it's not helpful to a beginner to just give them working code.

Comment: @Tim, this is true, the first `if` clause was the problem, but the other problem was the incorrect handling of the case when just `left` (or just `right`) child is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The following line of code appears to be the fatal flaw:

```
if (tree.emptyTree()){
```

I think that this case will be firing true when you really want to return 1 as being the base case.  Try this code:

```
public static int countLeaves(BinaryTree tree) {
    if (tree.getLeft() == null && tree.getRight() == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return countLeaves(tree.getLeft()) +
               countLeaves(tree.getRight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The problem was if (tree.getLeft() == null &&etc ... dosnt return true .. I had to use tree.getLeft().emptyTree() instead.